# 4 6v batteries, with one connected wrong way round?

Tags: reverse-polarity

Today i was working on a machine with 4 6v batteries connected in series.

It was in a building that was very dark and the batteries were covered in dirt and i briefly accidently fitted one of the batteries the wrong way around.

After i corrected the mistake i couldnt get 24v across the four batteries, only 18v, from wherever that battery was out of the voltmeter circuit.
Yet the same battery measured 6v on the meter, and load tested ok.

Could the polarity have been reversed on that battery after connecting it the wrong way around?

If so, does charging the 4 batteries in series correct this reverse polarity.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check the voltage on each battery individually when out of the circuit? Can you measure them when they are all connected?

Comment: Yeah, they all show 6v individually.

Comment: Can you measure them when they are in the circuit? Anyway, it sounds like something is wrong with that battery. Unless the battery was completely empty to start with, you shouldn't have reversed the polarity, but you may have overcharged it. If the battery has a built-in protection circuit, the protection circuit may have tripped.

Comment: In series: 6V + 6V + 6V *-* 6V = 12V

Comment: Can you load test all 4 batteries?